# What is the best way to implement Site Binding specific configuration in IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config, asp.net-web-api

We have a ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI Portal RIA (a mouthful, I know).  The Portal UI is implemented using extjs and static html (ie no views), and all dynamic behavior is driven via RESTful JSON service end points implemented via the `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.  Currently, the website is deployed in production as a **single site** with **two site bindings** (ie two different URLs) in IIS: one URL is internal and provides access to the full portal, the other is HTTPS and is intended to provide external authorized users access to the RESTful JSON API portion of the site.  Effectively, this means that while the internal URL allows full access to the site, ideally, **the external URL should**:

- Only allow respond to JSON requests
- Not allow access to the default page (eg index.htm)

What is the best way to accomplish this goal in IIS or otherwise?  Is there a better alternative to the shared site with multiple site binding configuration we are currently using?  Any insight would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution (from all those that involve coding your own solution) would be to implement an HTTP Module that intercepts all calls and do all the filtering logic in your code based on the domain name or IP.
Here is a very simple example of how you can do that: [Using ASP.NET HTTP Modules to restrict access by IP address](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16384/Using-ASP-NET-HTTP-Modules-to-restrict-access-by-I)

I am not aware of any way to accomplish your task purely by changing a configuration.

Comment: I was hopeful there would be a more configuration based solution.  I suppose I'll have to create my own :)